# S3 stored image with If-Modified-Since header not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, browser, amazon-s3, http-headers, browser-cache

Is there any way to load images from S3 to browser only if they were changed, by sending If-Modified-Since header?

It should be enabled by default on browsers and S3 but tests saying that images are loading on every refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 supports the `If-Modified-Since` header already, as well as the related `If-None-Match` (which uses an [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) instead of a date).

So, the way to load images only if they were changed is to actually use the `If-Modified-Since`, or `If-None-Match` if you have the Etag.  However, since you are talking about loading it to a browser, most browsers will already be doing this unless you have done something funky to disable browser caching.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html#RESTObjectGET-requests-request-headers for details on the supported headers.

Are you experiencing a situation where the browser is still loading the images from S3 even if they haven't been changed? If so, do you have more details on that, e.g. the browser, version, and something like a [Chrome network tab HAR file](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading?hl=en#copy-save-and-clear-network-information) illustrating the symptoms?

By default, it should just work on both sides with no custom changes.  I just replicated by uploading a fresh png image file to S3.  In a fresh browser window, I opened the dev tools and loaded the network tab.  I ensured that the 'disable caching' was UNticked, and 'preserve log' was ticked (to keep the log over multiple F5 refreshes).

I loaded the image and then hit F5 to reload twice.  The result was:

[image: Network tab screenshot]

As you can see, the first load was with a 200 status, the other requests received 304.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. Actually I read all this info on first google, but I could not find implementation guide. I'm serving html to browser from php/apache and I have image tags in the html with src path leading to S3 stored images, so I'm not conroling request headers that browser makes to S3. How can I enable them? Or, if they are enabled by default, then what should I enable on S3 side (meta data of images etc)?

Comment: It should work by default on both sides (client and server). I have edited the comment to show a screenshot of what you should see, and a description of how to replicate.  What symptom are you seeing that makes you think it *isn't* returning 304?

Comment: Had a further thought - as outlined in the edit, the browser will still issue a request to s3, with the If-Modified-Since header.  It's just that S3 will respond with 304 with no content and the browser will use it's local copy.  If what you actually want is for the browser to not send any messages to S3 at all, you need to add a custom header to each object in S3 -

Comment: `Cache-Control : max-age=100` where max-age is the number of seconds to cache it for.  If you do that, the browser will use the image from its local cache immediately without any request to S3, until the cache'd copy is over 100s old.  At that time it will issue another request to S3 with `If-Modified-Since`, and S3 will respond with 304 as above.  Then the browser will cache it for another 100s etc.  You can make max-age as long as you like.

Comment: The problem is resolved. I missed the github merge in which my colleague added isLocalhost() custom validation for images folder path couple months ago, so when I was testing from localhost, images were always loading from local folder, but not from s3 bucket, that's why I was always getting code 200 (ok). Tests on the live website showed that everythings works as it should and s3 successfully adds If-Modified-Since header. Crap. Thanks for the help, I will leave the question if someone will have the same issue.